# VS Code Vetur initialization is extremely slow

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, vetur

I am experiencing extremely slow Vetur initialisation after every time VS code is restarted.

It helps a bit if I don't `npm run serve` straight away into my development environment, because otherwise Vetur initialisation would just hang forever. But it is still very slow even if I let it run for a bit before starting to do my work.

Google doesn't seem to be able to find an answer for this, so I would appreciate if anyone got a hint as to the problem?